# What does this for loop mean?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for(String name: names){
   System.out.printli(name);
}
```

What does the first line mean? I only understand the `for(int i=0; i<=10;i++)` format.

Comment: Did you consider looking up the language specification?

Comment: I was about to ask this same question, luckily I was wise enough to come across this. Great help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html).

Your code reads as `for each String name in names`.

Comment: Oh thank goodness I came across this, I was about to ask this same question. Wouldn't have been wise.

Answer (score 2):

That's the "enhanced" for loop that is available in newer versions of java.  In "spoken language," it would be "for each value 'name' in names".  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html has a pretty good explanation.